# How to get substring with javascript code from HTML code in Java?

Tags: android, string, split, substring

I parse one web page and need to get min and max values for slider elements. All page i parse with Jsoup, but this values i can't get this it.. they in javascript blocks.

```
<script>
    $(function(){ $("#p_slider").slider({ range:true, step:1000, min:2000, max:49490.00, values:[2000,49490.00], slide:function(event, ui) {
    $("#p_from").val((ui.values[0] != 2000)?ui.values[0]:"");
    $("#p_to").val((ui.values[1] != 49490.00)?ui.values[1]:"");
    $("#p_from").change();
    $("#p_to").change();
} }); });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() { $("#filter_543_slider").slider({ range:true, step:1000, min:0, max:17600.000, values:[0,17600.000], slide:function(event, ui) {
                    $("#f543_from").val((ui.values[0] != 0)?ui.values[0]:"");
                    $("#f543_to").val((ui.values[1] != 17600.000)?ui.values[1]:"");
                    $("#f543_from").change();
                    $("#f543_to").change();
                } }); });
</script>
```

I need to get min and max values for #p_slider and #filter_543_slider

Now i try with this code:

```
String min = bodyHTML.split("[$(\"#"+searchingIdent+"\").slider({]")[1].split("[min:]")[1].split(",")[0];
String max = bodyHTML.split("[$(\"#"+searchingIdent+"\").slider({]")[1].split("[max:]")[1].split(",")[0];
```

But i catch error: err:length=1; index=1

And this splitting getting too much time.. +5-10 seconds

Please, tell me how to get needed substrings correct and fast.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomment to use regular expressions. I wrote this one here for you:

```regex
\$\("#([a-z0-9_]+)"\)\.slider\([^\)]+min:([0-9\.]+)[^\)]+max:([0-9\.]+)
```

This one checks for a jquery line which expects a id (or better the # sign) and after that a slider function where the parameters min and max are inside.

Try also this [fiddler](http://fiddle.re/ucej6) to check my result.

The first result is the id, the second one the min value and the third one is the max value.